# Choosing the correct diodes

Tags: circuit-design, diodes

I want some guidance on which diodes (circled in red) would be appropriate to substitute on this drum machine from the 1960s.

Fuse is 0.5 AMP, the scan didn't catch the "."

All resistors are 1/2 Watt rated

Q63 is P-3139 Solitron TO-3 MOS-fet transistor 60V 15A

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What's the package?

Comment: Do you have any information about how much current each of the +17 V, +1 V and +6 V voltage rails need to be able to supply?

Comment: all point to point so thru-hole varieties, thank you

Comment: schematic mentions all resistors shall be 1/2 watt rated, so I assume that current

Comment: Ok, so ~500 mA max 0.5W through 1.8 ohms. Strange that there's a 5A slow-blow fuse on the primary...

Comment: @soapygoat Do D32 and D33 look about like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Vkh.png)? (Those are from a 1967 instrument I have here.)

Comment: Are you making a reproduction, or do you have one where there is a fault and you're repairing it?

Comment: @periblepsis yes! Big boys.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am replacing the multi can capacitor, it has components off the can so I was going to spare the zener and carbon comp resistors that I would be messing with, they deserve to be laid to rest after 60 years! The Maestro service manual only lists components with their Maestro p/n, no specs on the zeners or rectifying diodes.

Comment: @soapygoat Those are 8D2 germanium diodes in the picture. They were being actively sold by 1960 (you can find them being sold in the February 1960 `Practical Wireless` magazine on page 814.) Good luck finding a datasheet on them, though! So if they look like mine, they may be germanium. Germanium became popular and widely used before silicon took over a decade later. Those I show test out at about 550 mV with 5 mA forward current running through them.

Comment: @JohnDoty I bet it was .5 amp fuse but the scan quality didn't catch the "."

Comment: I have reopened this question as it has a very good answer, plus related rationale in comments, and as the question is clear, and as the solution can be very reasonably be adduced from the available information. It may be that the reason to close was not what the close voters intended, as sometimes happens. If this is the case people may vote to close again but should provide an explanation in comments so that it is clear why it is really being voted to close.

Comment: It is interesting that you describe Q63 as a mosfet. In that role it appears to be a classic BJT  NPN transistor in emitter follower mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diodes D32 and D33 are used in the rectification part of the power supply, so rectifier diodes would be appropriate.

For a drum machine, I doubt if the current exceeeds 1 A, so 1N4004 diodes should work fine. (That's a commonly-available diode, usually cheaper than the 50 V 1N4001.)

Assuming that the current draw on the output rails is not large (because of the 1.8 Ω resistor), then Z1 would be calculated from the desired output voltage (17 V) plus the \$V_{BE}\$ value of transistor Q63, call it 0.7 V, so something close to a 17.7 V Zener diode would be needed. I can't find that exact Zener voltage, but, as kindly pointed out by Dave Tweed in a [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695245/choosing-the-correct-diodes/695246?noredirect=1#comment1851068_695246), an 18 V Zener diode such as a 1N5248 would be appropriate. The 17 V rail probably doesn't need to be very exact, there will be a (current-dependent) voltage drop due to the 1.8 Ω resistor, and there will not be a lot of current through that diode, so a 500 mW rating should be good.

For Z2, a 6 V 500 mW Zener diode should be fine.

N.B.: I am not an electronics engineer, I only dabble.

Comment: You've missed that there are also two zener diodes.

Comment: For ``Z2`` assume a 6 V zener diode such as a ``TZX6V2C`` would be sufficient to generate the +6 V rail. Given the 3.3k resistor, think the +6 V rail only needs to supply a few milliamps.

Comment: For ``Z1`` do we need to know the characteristics of the ``regulator Q63`` to determine the zener diode voltage to generate the regulated output for the +17 V rail?

Comment: Z1 needs to be **higher** than the output voltage by the \$V_{BE}\$ of the transistor plus the drop across the 1.8 Ω resistor. So a diode rated for 18 V would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you, I've incorporated your correction.